# Qual a função da opção Deploy no Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, deploy

Comunidade, quando fui compilar um projeto recebi a mensagem que deveria marcar a opção `Deploy`. Daí surgiu uma dúvida, gostaria de uma explicação (quanto mais detalhada melhor :) ) sobre a opção `Deploy` (<kbd>Project</kbd>-<kbd>Properties</kbd>) do Visual Studio.

Aqui mesmo no StOv encontrei:

> Implantação ou deployment consiste em uma série de atividades
>   necessárias para obter um programa disponível para uso fora de um
>   ambiente de desenvolvimento (por exemplo, em sites da web, PCs,
>   smartphones e/ou tablets).

Porém não esclareceu totalmente minha dúvida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É comum em uma solution termos vários projetos. Alguns destes projetos nós não gostaríamos que estivessem no deploy da aplicação.

Exemplo de um projeto assim? Um que contém apenas testes unitários. Um projeto assim dentro da solution não deve entrar no deploy da aplicação. Portanto, não deveria ser marcado para deploy nesta janela de configuração.

Comment: Gostei da resposta, se possível tente adicionar mais detalhes como, por exemplo, o que acontece se marcar a opção Deploy sem necessidade? A compilação é mais demorada? Pode dificultar Depuração do projeto? etc...